# Getting data to transfer from one TableViewController to another once a date passes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm working on an app which is date based. I'm trying to get information to pass from one TableViewController to another.

It's a notification based app that reminds the user that something comes out today. So on the date it comes out, I'd like it to come off the release list and go onto the released list (So if something comes out the Nov.8th, on that date it'll be moved to the released list).

I'm having trouble getting it to work. I used the below codes and the date comes and goes without anything happening, it still shows it on the release list.

Below is the code I used on the release list:

```
let startOfToday = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date()) as NSDate
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "release_date > %@", startOfToday)
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```

And here's the code on the released list:

```
let startOfToday = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date()) as NSDate
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "release_date < %@", startOfToday)
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```

Here's the code for the FreshReleaseTableViewController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import UserNotifications

class FreshReleaseTableViewController: UITableViewController{
    var freshreleases = [Release_Date]()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //create a new button
        let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
        //set image for button
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "Mic App Logo.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)

        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .full
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
    }

    @objc func editAction() {
        let viewController = AddfreshreleaseViewController()
        navigationController?.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let fetchRequest = Release_Date.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<Release_Date>

        let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "artist", ascending: true)
        let sortDescriptor2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "album", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2]
        do {
            freshreleases = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch let error {
            print("Could not fetch because of error: \(error).")
        }

        let startOfToday = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date()) as NSDate
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "release_date > %@", startOfToday)
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return freshreleases.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FreshReleaseCellIdentifier", for: indexPath)

        let freshrelease = freshreleases[indexPath.row]

            cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

        let artist = freshrelease.artist ?? ""
        let album = freshrelease.album ?? ""
        cell.textLabel?.text = artist + "'s\nnew album '" + album + "'\nreleases"

        if let date = freshrelease.release_date as Date? {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        } else {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""
        }

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if freshreleases.count > indexPath.row {
            let freshrelease = freshreleases[indexPath.row]

            // Remove notification
            if let identifier = freshrelease.release_dateId {
                let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
                center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [identifier])
            }

            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
            context.delete(freshrelease)
            freshreleases.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch let error {
                print("Could not save \(error)")
            }
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
    }

    @available(iOS 11.0, *)

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?

    {
        let modifyAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Edit", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
            print("Update action ...")
            let MainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
            let vc : UIViewController = MainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FreshReleaseEdit") as UIViewController
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            success(true)

        })
        modifyAction.title = "Edit"
        modifyAction.backgroundColor = .blue

        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [modifyAction])
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

And here's the code for the ReleasedTableViewController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import UserNotifications

class ReleasedTableViewController: UITableViewController{
    var freshreleases = [Release_Date]()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //create a new button
        let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
        //set image for button
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "Mic App Logo.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)

        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .full
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let fetchRequest = Release_Date.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<Release_Date>

        let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "album", ascending: true)
        let sortDescriptor2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "artist", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2]
        do {
            freshreleases = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch let error {
            print("Could not fetch because of error: \(error).")
        }

        let startOfToday = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date()) as NSDate
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "release_date < %@", startOfToday)
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return freshreleases.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FreshReleaseCellIdentifier", for: indexPath)

        let freshrelease = freshreleases[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

        let artist = freshrelease.artist ?? ""
        let album = freshrelease.album ?? ""
        cell.textLabel?.text = artist + "'s \nnew album '" + album + "'\nreleases"

        if let date = freshrelease.release_date as Date? {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        } else {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""
        }

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if freshreleases.count > indexPath.row {
            let freshrelease = freshreleases[indexPath.row]

            // Remove notification
            if let identifier = freshrelease.release_dateId {
                let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
                center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [identifier])
            }

            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
            context.delete(freshrelease)
            freshreleases.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch let error {
                print("Could not save \(error)")
            }
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

        }
    }

    @available(iOS 11.0, *)
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                            leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?

    {
        let modifyAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Update", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
            print("Update action ...")
            success(true)
        })
        modifyAction.title = "Edit"
        modifyAction.backgroundColor = .blue

        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [modifyAction])
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use your view as if it was a model. Table views should not be passing data to other views. Create an underlying model and have it inform both table views as to what to display.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of potential solutions to this.

The easiest I would propose is that your view controllers listen out for [`UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdidbecomeactivenotification?language=objc). When this notification fires then you can run rebuild your fetch request and execute it again. This should then give you the up-to-date variation of the list.

An alternative option is to slightly change your data model to include an `isReleased` flag in your data model. Now in your app delegate you can implement [`applicationDidBecomeActive`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622956-applicationdidbecomeactive?language=objc). When this method is called you can trigger an update of your database to refresh the `isReleased` flag. In your view controllers you can make use of [`NSFetchedResultController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller) and change the predicate of your query to:

```
 // Unreleased movies
 fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isReleased = NO")

 // Released movies
 fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isReleased = YES")
```

The fetched result controllers have a delegate protocol that lets you listen for changes to your underlying data store, giving you an opportunity to update the UI.

Comment: I have this added: func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) { } in the AppDelegate.Swift file. Is this the appropriate location for it? If so, I still can't get the information over to the released list.

Comment: I’m not to familiar with changing the data model. How would I go about setting the isReleased flag?

Comment: I am assuming that you are using Core Data. You would need to add the property to your data model file on the `Release_Date`  entity.

Comment: I added the isReleased flag to the Core Data and still can't get it to work. The only thing I can think of is that maybe I placed the NSFetchedResultController in the wrong place? Do I need to add this class as well? class NSFetchedResultsController<ResultType> : NSObject where ResultType : NSFetchRequestResult

Comment: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isReleased = YES")
        
        tableView.reloadData()
    }